# Can't push to master via heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

thanks in advance for your help.

When I try to run

```
$ git push heroku master
```

I get an error:

```
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
      Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!
```

I've updated my Gemfile to read as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

group :production, :staging do
   gem "pg"
 end

 group :development, :test do
   gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
 end

 # Gems used only for assets and not required
 # in production environments by default.
 group :assets do
   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.4'
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'

   # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
   # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
 end

 gem 'jquery-rails'

 # To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
 # gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

 # To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
 # gem 'jbuilder'

 # Use unicorn as the app server
 # gem 'unicorn'

 # Deploy with Capistrano
 # gem 'capistrano'

 # To use debugger
 # gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

my Gemfile.lock file looks like:

```
 GEM
   remote: https://rubygems.org/
   specs:
     actionmailer (3.2.3)
       actionpack (= 3.2.3)
       mail (~> 2.4.4)
     actionpack (3.2.3)
       activemodel (= 3.2.3)
       activesupport (= 3.2.3)
       builder (~> 3.0.0)
       erubis (~> 2.7.0)
       journey (~> 1.0.1)
       rack (~> 1.4.0)
       rack-cache (~> 1.2)
       rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
       sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
     activemodel (3.2.3)
       activesupport (= 3.2.3)
       builder (~> 3.0.0)
     activerecord (3.2.3)
       activemodel (= 3.2.3)
       activesupport (= 3.2.3)
       arel (~> 3.0.2)
       tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
     activeresource (3.2.3)
       activemodel (= 3.2.3)
       activesupport (= 3.2.3)
     activesupport (3.2.3)
       i18n (~> 0.6)
       multi_json (~> 1.0)
     arel (3.0.2)
     builder (3.0.4)
     coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
       railties (~> 3.2.0)
     coffee-script (2.2.0)
       coffee-script-source
       execjs
     coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
     erubis (2.7.0)
     execjs (1.4.0)
       multi_json (~> 1.0)
     hike (1.2.1)
     i18n (0.6.1)
     journey (1.0.4)
     jquery-rails (2.2.0)
       railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
       thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
     json (1.7.6)
     mail (2.4.4)
       i18n (>= 0.4.0)
  mime-types (~> 1.16)
  treetop (~> 1.4.8)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.5.0)
pg (0.14.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.4)
rack-cache (1.2)
  rack (>= 0.4)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  rack
rack-test (0.6.2)
  rack (>= 1.0)
rails (3.2.3)
  actionmailer (= 3.2.3)
  actionpack (= 3.2.3)
  activerecord (= 3.2.3)
  activeresource (= 3.2.3)
  activesupport (= 3.2.3)
  bundler (~> 1.0)
  railties (= 3.2.3)
railties (3.2.3)
  actionpack (= 3.2.3)
  activesupport (= 3.2.3)
  rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  rdoc (~> 3.4)
  thor (~> 0.14.6)
rake (10.0.3)
rdoc (3.12)
  json (~> 1.4)
sass (3.2.5)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
  railties (~> 3.2.0)
  sass (>= 3.1.10)
  tilt (~> 1.3)
sprockets (2.1.3)
  hike (~> 1.2)
  rack (~> 1.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
  sqlite3 (>= 1.3.3)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
  polyglot
  polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
uglifier (1.3.0)
  execjs (>= 0.3.0)
  multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)

 PLATFORMS
   ruby

 DEPENDENCIES
   coffee-rails (~> 3.2.2)
   jquery-rails
   pg
   rails (= 3.2.3)
   sass-rails (~> 3.2.4)
   sqlite3-ruby
   uglifier (>= 1.2.3)
```

I've run Bundle Install and Bundle Update to no avail.

Comment: Make sure the files are committed before you push. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323887/sqlite3-reference-deploying-simple-heroku-rails-aplication

Comment: begs for a question, does `gem install sqlite3` even succeed locally? Although Heroku doesn't use SQLite3 but I think the push will fail as long as any of your gem's are not installed properly.

Comment: You guys are life savers. THANK YOU!  I had to inject:
    group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    end
    group :production do
   gem 'pg'
   end

Then run bundle install without production then:

I've resolved the problem. It was a bad use of git.

I needed to update the changes in Gemfile and Gemfile.lock:

First compile:

$ bundle
then:

$ git add Gemfile
$ git add Gemfile.lock

$ git commit -m 'Added pg adapter gem'
$ git push heroku master
Now Heroku updates OK

And now run the postgresql database:

$ heroku run rake db:migrate

So helpful, thank you for finding that answer!